# Bash read & parse from XML

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have an XML file that contains a URL, when I'm running:

```
firefox xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//site' -v . -n <~/Desktop/data.xml
```

Instead of redirecting to the URL it gives me the Firefox version. What is wrong? How can I make Firefox to redirect with the URL result?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `firefox $(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//site' -v . -n <~/Desktop/data.xml)`?

Comment: Ohhh yeah....thats all I needed...Thank's it was all because of brakets:-)

Answer (score 0):

Below command works, it will open firefox and redirect to url from xml file.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//site' -v . -n < link.xml | xargs firefox
```